# C++/LabVIEW interop: error extracting data from LabVIEW array/ unexpected type conversion in function parameter

Tags: c++, interop, compiler-errors, type-conversion, labview

I'm using [Cluebat-man's LabVIEW-C++ array interoperability class,](http://msmvps.com/blogs/vandooren/archive/2006/08/10/Fun-with-template-classes_3A00_-Manipulating-LabVIEW-arrays-in-C_2B002B002C00_-part-3.aspx) and I'm getting an error extracting the data from from the array. Or, rather, the data extraction appears to succeed, but build fails when I try to use the data a line later.

(Context: The program is designed to implement Manjunath et al's peer-group filtering; the function is designed to extract the hue plane of an image. I'm fairly certain it's not a problem with the specific function, aside from perhaps its declaration of parameters, because the same problem crops up later in the program when I try to use the results from `getHuePlane()`)

```
#ifndef IO_TYPE //Normal arrays or LabVIEW?
#define I_TYPE  /* int* */ CLvArrayHandlePtr<unsigned __int32, 2>
#define O_TYPE /* int* */ CLvArrayHandlePtr<unsigned __int8, 2>
#define IO_TYPE
#endif

#ifndef USING_LABVIEW_DEFINED
#define USING_LABVIEW //remove if not
#define USING_LABVIEW_DEFINED
#endif
```

Extraction and function call:

```
#include "LvArrayIndexer.h"
#include "LvArrayTemplate.h"

O_TYPE pgf(I_TYPE HSLimage, int width, int height, int halfWindowSize, int noiseThreshold) {
#ifdef USING_LABVIEW
    size_t size[2] = {width, height};
    HSLimage.Resize(size);
    CLvArrayIndexer<unsigned __int32, 2 > baseImgIndexer(HSLimage);

    CLvArrayHandlePtr<unsigned __int8, 2 > hueImage;
    hueImage.Resize(size);
    CLvArrayIndexer<unsigned __int8, 2 > hueImgIndexer(hueImage);

    int LvImageData[width][height];
#else
    int hueImage[width][height];
#endif
    int hueImageData[width][height];
    int windowSize = 2 * halfWindowSize - 1;
    int windowLength = windowSize * windowSize;
    int window[windowSize][windowSize];
    int flattenedWindow[windowLength];
    vector<int> peerGroup;
    int currentValue;

#ifdef USING_LABVIEW
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
            LvImageData[x][y] = baseImgIndexer[x][y];

    hueImageData = getHuePlane(LvImageData, width, height);
#else
    hueImageData = getHuePlane(HSLimage, width, height);
#endif
//Function continues
}
```

Function definition:

```
int* getHuePlane(int* HSLimage, int width, int height) {
    int hueImage[width][height];
    double calcValue;

    /*Get hue plane
     *AL HU SA LU ->AL HU.SA LU -> AL HUF
     *AL HU -> AL.HU -> 0.HU -> HU
     */
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
            calcValue = int(double(HSLimage[x][y]) / 65536); //A-H-S-L; removes S-L
            calcValue = (calcValue / 256) - int(calcValue / 256);
            calcValue = calcValue * 256;
            hueImage[x][y] = int(calcValue);
        }
    }

    return hueImage;
}
```

The error is:

```
pgf.cpp:88:58: error: cannot convert 'int (*)[(((unsigned int)(((int)height) + -0x000000001)) + 1)]' to 'int*' for argument '1' to 'int* getHuePlane(int*, int, int)'
```

System information:

- IDE:Netbeans 7.1
- Compiler: MinGW (gcc v4.6.2)
- Make: GNU make 3.79.1
- System: Windows 7 version 6.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing the error is on this line:

```
hueImageData = getHuePlane(LvImageData, width, height);
```

The reason is because of type missmatch: `LvImageData` is defined as `int [][]` while `getHuePlane` expects `int *`.

Also, you should also get an error on this line (in `getHuePlane`):

```
calcValue = int(double(HSLimage[x][y]) / 65536); //A-H-S-L; removes S-L
```

This is because `HSLimage` in the function is an `int *` while you try to access it as `int [][]` (or `int *[]` as the argument type should really be).

Comment: Huh. I was under the impression that that (passing the name of the array as a pointer) was how you passed arrays to function. I take it [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com) is outdated on this?

At any rate, I'll give it a try - thanks!

Comment: Yep, that was the problem. I ended up switching over entirely to vectors - thanks!